# what is haystack ,elastic search, elasticsearch_dsl in django?

Tags: django, elasticsearch, django-haystack, elasticsearch-dsl

can anyone explain **what is :**

```
1. haystack  
2. elastic search
3. elasticsearch_dsl
```

what is the purpose to use this
in Django project.

Comment: You are better off reading on respective websites.

Comment: Look at each project site, It explains what you need. [Haystack](https://haystacksearch.org) allows you to write python code to perform search on different search engines with the same code, [Elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/elasticsearch-intro.html) is a search engine and document-oriented database and [elasticsearch-dsl](https://elasticsearch-dsl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) is a python library to interact with elasticsearch.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you want to have **this** definitions:

- [`django-haystack`](https://github.com/django-haystack/django-haystack) - Python library, by which you can add searching features in your django project. It has familiar API that allows you to plug in different search backends (Solr, **ElasticSearch**, Whoosh, Xapian, etc).
- [`elasticsearch-py`](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-py) - Official **low-level** Python client for Elasticsearch.
- [`elasticsearch-dsl-py`](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-dsl-py) - Is a **high-level** python library, built on top of the official low-level client *(elasticsearch-py)*.